# How to delete and update the content in second file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following two files `test.txt` and `test1.txt.` I want to update the data of `test.txt` in to `test1.txt` under `abc.com`, however, first it has to remove the existing data so final output looks like `test1.txt` under output file section

test.txt

```
10.100.4.10
10.100.4.11
10.100.4.12
```

test1.txt

```
[abc.com]
10.100.44.10
10.100.44.11

[xyz.com]
10.100.55.10
10.100.55.11
```

[etc..]

OUTPUT FILE

test1.txt

```
[abc.com]
10.100.4.10
10.100.4.11
10.100.4.12

[xyz.com]
10.100.55.10
10.100.55.11
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code (to your question) of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Have a look at this link, it points to the right direction : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker

Answer (score 0):

If you know the address `abc.com` beforehand and that the entries are separated by a blank line then use the following sed commands. First one deletes the lines between abc.com and the first blank line and the second inserts the text you want from test1.txt.

```
$ sed '/^\[abc\.com\]/,/^$/{/^\[abc\.com\]/!{/^$/!d}}' test.txt | sed '/^\[abc.com\]/r test1.txt'
[abc.com]
10.100.4.10
10.100.4.11
10.100.4.12

[xyz.com]
10.100.55.10
10.100.55.11
```

Comment: Now, if i run manually below command its working.  However, in script when i called the domain name and file its not working.  

/bin/sed -i  '/\babc.com/,/^$/{/^[0-9]/d};/\babc.com/r test.txt' /tmp/test1.txt


Below is the call in the bash script. I tried to echo following command with the value and its taking correct value. What went wrong.  

/bin/sed -i '/\b$dmname/,/^$/{/^[0-9]/d};/\b"$dmname"/r $file' /tmp/test1.txt

Comment: solved. used below in bash script /bin/sed -i "/\b$dmname/,/^$/{/^[0-9]/d};/\b"$dmname"/r $file" /tmp/test1.txt

Comment: Yes if you want bash variable expansion you have to use double quotes. I also see you are using a different deletion criteria. If all the lines you need to delete begins with a number it is fine, but if there is any whitespace before the numbers it will be skipped